# Publishing UI as angular with Asp.Net Core as API on Azure

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure, deployment

Im am having an issue when deploying my angular project and asp.net core with identity to Azure. The issue is that in order for identity to work both the asp.net core project and the angular project need to be in the same folder. But when I publish them in the same folder it returns a 404 when calling the methods in the API.

So does anyone know what the structure in the folder should look like in the wwwroot folder for identity to work properly?

See the image on my current structure. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXsrF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look at pushing the Angular site to a static website.  You can do that with the Azure resource or just put it in a storage account and enable the static web for the storage account.

You want them separate so that you can scale the API app service as needed.

Also look at using Azure functions to have serverless API's.